# Egit staged after commit?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I'm using egit for eclipse since today

but there is a problem.

I commited a file(works perfectly), but after the commit the file is staged to commit again?
and with "git status" the file is listed "Changes to be committed:"
But without any changes "git diff" has no output.

What's the matter?

commiting in command line seems to work as intended. Is it a general egit problem ?

greetings

Comment: EGit is still under development (to put it nicely), and it's a completely independent implementation of git - so unfortunately though using real git on the command line will work great, EGit may still have plenty of problems. Hopefully it'll be improving fast, though, as Eclipse is pretty popular and I believe it's moving toward git... they at least have git mirrors of their repos now.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like [**bug 307560**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=307560)

> Basically, there appears to be a situation where EGit or JGit change the file mode of a file, either immediately pre- or post- commit, and then the file gets marked as dirty in the project.
>   Weirdly, EGit picks up the file mode change enough to mark the file as dirty, but not enough to allow you to check in the new file mode change (were you to want to) -- even with the dirty file marker, attempting to commit tells you "No changed items were selected. Do you wish to
>   amend the last commit?"

Comment: thanks this has been bugging me for awhile; nice to know there is a ticket for it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to drag changed files from "Unstaged Changes" window to "Staged Changes" window