# Why does eGit commit dialog not automatically select all files when I commit a project?

Tags: git, egit

I don't understand one thing about eGit...

when I commit a project, often (usually.. always?) not all files are checked. Why is that?

and is there any way that I can make it select all files by default?

Comment: possibly same as that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691782/egit-staged-after-commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EGit 1.2 and lower releases do not automatically select untracked files in the commit dialog.

This behavior has changed in the 1.3 release due out on Feburary 24th, 2012.

A preference was added to the *Team > Git > Commit Dialog* preference page to enable this option so the files will be automatically selected.

This was added based on the bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=345887).

Comment: great news... can't wait... still new to eclipse so I don't understand if plugins auto-update? or I must remember to check for new one on the 24th

Comment: It will be available from the 3.7 (Indigo) update site here: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo  Automatic updates can be configured from the _Install/Update > Automatic Updates_ preference page